# How to search string array and return name of the item in the array?

Tags: java, android, search, arrays

I'm new to Android programming.
Alright, now I have a string array like this:

```
<string-array name="mStrArray">
    <item name="item1a">text to be searched no1</item>
    <item name="item1b">text to be searched no2</item>
    <item name="item2a">text to be searched no3</item>
    <item name="item2b">text to be searched no4</item>
</string-array>
```

I search the array like this, and return results into a list adapter:

```
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mStrArray);
        for (String s : names) {
            int i = s.indexOf(searchKeyword);
            if (i >= 0) {
               //add results to listview adapter
               countryList.add(new Country(s, ""));
            }
        }
```

**My problem is**, I can't find a way to get the name of the item inside the array from which the result was found.
So in this eg. If I search for no3, I would get the name of the item "item2a" and also the value.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use another simplexmlframework to deal with you issue

Comment: If you're using string arrays that you know wont change, why not just use two arrays - one for item names and one for the text to be searched. When a match occurs, you can fetch the corresponding name using the index.

Comment: @akashasia thanks that's a great idea, I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so thanks to akashasia I managed to find a solution, it's not very elegant but at least it works for now.
So here is what I did:
I made 2 arrays like akashasia said, 1 for the item names and 1 for the text to be searched, like this:

```
<string-array name="mStrArray">
    <item>text to be searched no1</item>
    <item>text to be searched no2</item>
    <item>text to be searched no3</item>
    <item>text to be searched no4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="mStrArrayValues">
    <item>item1a</item>
    <item>item1b</item>
    <item>item2a</item>
    <item>item2b</item>
</string-array>
```

And I changed the code to this:

```
String[] arrB = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mStrArray);
    for (String s : arrB) {
        int i = s.indexOf(searchKeyword);
        if (i >= 0) {
             int position = -1;
             for(int j = 0; j < arrB.length; j++) {
                if(arrB[j] == s) {
                    position = j;
                    break;
                }
        }

        ..
        String[] arrBV = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mStrArrayValues);

        //finally I got the name of the value :-D
        String mySc = arrBV[position];
        //some code..           
                }
            }
```

P.S This is probably not the best way to do this. So if anyone has thoughts or improvements, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

my advice is java.util.Arrays has binarysearch method aceepting multiple option ,that will help u i think,

[Arraysapi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)